# Haskell: HList and optional parameters

Tags: haskell, hlist

I've been trying to use [HList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.2.3) to create records.

I've been using the operators defined in [HList-GHCSyntax](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HList/0.2.3/doc/html/Data-HList-GhcSyntax.html).

It so far works quite nicely, allowing me to write things like this:

```
myRecord = 
  (param1 .=. "param1value") .*. 
  (param2 .=. "param2value") .*. 
  emptyRecord
```

This allows me to do the following:

```
myRecord .!. param1
```

and the following:

```
myRecord .!. param3
```

throws a compile error as expected. This works great if `param3` is required, as I get compile time parameter checking.

But I also want to deal with the case where `param3` is optional. How can I do this?

---

**Edit:** The following seems to work (`Empty` is an empty type):

```
getOptional r l = (hLeftUnion r ((l .=. Empty) .*. emptyRecord)) .!. l
```

But I don't really know how to check for `Empty` in calling code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with defining `getOptional` is determining the result type.  If one tries:

```
class GetOptional r l v | r l -> v where
  getOptional :: l -> Record r -> Maybe vs
```

or

```
class GetOptional r l v | r l -> v where
  getOptional :: l -> Record r -> Maybe v
```

Then `v` can be determined by looking up `l` in `r` when present, but if `l` is not in `r` then from where should `v` come?  Pick () or Empty?  Leaving off the functional dependency makes the user supply a type annotation somewhere.

Perhaps a better way is to provide a default value (like fromMaybe):

```
class GetOptional r l v where
  getOptional :: l -> v -> Record r -> v
```

A more complicated version might supply a function to consume an existing value `(v->w)` and a default value `w`.

This works for me:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
import Data.HList.FakePrelude(HEq,HTrue,HFalse)
import Data.HList.HListPrelude(HNil(HNil),HCons(HCons))
import Data.HList.GhcSyntax((.=.),(.*.))
import Data.HList.Record(Record(Record),LVPair(LVPair),emptyRecord)

class GetOptional l r v where
  getOptional :: l -> v -> Record r -> v

instance GetOptional l HNil v where
  getOptional _ v _ = v

instance ( HEq l l' b
         , GetOptional' b l (HCons (LVPair l' v') r) v
         )
         => GetOptional l (HCons (LVPair l' v') r) v where
  getOptional l v (Record r) = getOptional' (undefined :: b) l v r

class GetOptional' b l r v where
  getOptional' :: b -> l -> v -> r -> v

instance GetOptional' HTrue l (HCons (LVPair l v) r) v where
  getOptional' _ _ _ (HCons (LVPair v) _) = v

instance ( GetOptional l r v
         )
         => GetOptional' HFalse l (HCons (LVPair l' v') r) v where
  getOptional' _ l v (HCons _ r) = getOptional l v (Record r)


data L1 = L1
data L2 = L2

e = emptyRecord
f = L1 .=. True .*. emptyRecord

-- test1 :: Bool
test1 = getOptional L1 False f
-- test2 :: Bool
test2 = getOptional L1 False e
-- test3 :: ()
test3 = getOptional L2 () f
-- test4 gives a type error:
-- test4 = getOptional L1 () f
```

I also include below second implementation of this using "higher level" HList predicates.  This removes the GetOptional type class and makes getOptional a simple function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
import Data.HList.FakePrelude(HFalse,HTrue)
import Data.HList.HListPrelude(HMember,hMember)
import Data.HList.GhcSyntax((.=.),(.*.))
import Data.HList.Record(RecordLabels,Record,HasField(hLookupByLabel),recordLabels,emptyRecord)

-- This type is inferred properly
-- getOptional :: ( RecordLabels r ls
--                , HMember l ls b
--                , GetOptional' b l r v )
--               =>  l -> v -> Record r -> v
getOptional l v rec = getOptional' (hMember l (recordLabels rec)) l v rec

class GetOptional' b l r v where
  getOptional' :: b -> l -> v -> Record r -> v

instance GetOptional' HFalse l rec v where
  getOptional' _ _ v _ = v

instance ( HasField l r v )
         => GetOptional' HTrue l r v where
  getOptional' _ l _ r = hLookupByLabel l r


data L1 = L1
data L2 = L2

e = emptyRecord
f = L1 .=. True .*. emptyRecord

-- test1 :: Bool
test1 = getOptional L1 False f
-- test2 :: Bool
test2 = getOptional L1 False e
-- test3 :: ()
test3 = getOptional L2 () f
-- test4 gives a type error:
-- test4 = getOptional L1 () f
```

EDIT: Here is the Maybe version which needs type annotations for all the Nothing answers:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
import Data.HList.FakePrelude(HFalse,HTrue)
import Data.HList.HListPrelude(HMember,hMember)
import Data.HList.GhcSyntax((.=.),(.*.))
import Data.HList.Record(RecordLabels,Record,HasField(hLookupByLabel),recordLabels,emptyRecord)
import Data.HList.TypeCastGeneric1
import Data.HList.TypeEqGeneric1
import Data.HList.Label5

-- getOptional :: ( RecordLabels r ls
--                , HMember l ls b
--                , GetOptional' b l r v )
--               =>  l -> Record r -> Maybe v
getOptional l rec = getOptional' (hMember l (recordLabels rec)) l rec

class GetOptional' b l r v where
  getOptional' :: b -> l -> Record r -> Maybe v

instance GetOptional' HFalse l rec v where
  getOptional' _ _ _ = Nothing

instance ( HasField l r v )
         => GetOptional' HTrue l r v where
  getOptional' _ l r = Just (hLookupByLabel l r)


data L1 = L1
data L2 = L2

e = emptyRecord
f = L1 .=. True .*. emptyRecord

test1 = getOptional L1 f
test2 = getOptional L1 e
test3 = getOptional L2 f
-- test4 :: Maybe () -- this would be a type error
-- test4 = getOptional L1 f

main = print ( test1 -- inferred becuase it is Just {}
             , test2 :: Maybe () -- must specify for Nothing
             , test3 :: Maybe () -- must specify for Nothing
             )
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, this looks good! One follow up question, could you add another response that allows one to make the default value `Nothing`, and the return value `Just v`? Most of the parameters don't have defaults, if they're empty, they're simply empty (which is different to blank).

Comment: Replacing (default :: v) with (Nothing :: forall a . Maybe a) is like your Empty before.  It does not help with type inference.

Comment: I have added the Maybe version, with the type annotations to make it work.

Comment: I know I'm asking a lot here, but would you mind giving an example, similar thing but using the Records package here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/records-0.1.1.6 . I'll create a bounty and reward it to you, as all this has been really helpful for me (and is hopefully helpful to others).

Comment: There is an example: `e`, `f`, and `test1,2,3` at the end of my code sample.

Comment: Chris: Is `e`, `f` using the `Records` package, not `HList`?